# Проверка валидности указателя в DLL

Tags: c++, указатели, dll

Задумал написать DLL. Чтобы DLL была универсальной настолько, насколько это вообще возможно - решил использовать минимальный "C" интерфейс и хендлы. То есть в самой библиотеке у меня по полной используется ООП и STL, но экспортируются только функции оперирующие с хендлами. Небольшой пример:

.h файл

```
/**
 * \brief Хендл ресурса статической геометрии
 */
typedef void* RglGeometryResource;

/**
 * \brief Создание ресурса геометрии
 * \param vertices Массив исходных вершин
 * \param indices Массив индексов
 */
extern "C" RENDERERGL_API RglGeometryResource __cdecl rglCreateGeometryResource(RglVertex* vertices, unsigned vertexCount, unsigned* indices, unsigned indexCount);

/**
 * \brief Уничтожение ресурса геометрии
 * \param resource Указатель на хендл ресурса
 */
extern "C" RENDERERGL_API void __cdecl rglDestroyGeometryResource(RglGeometryResource* resource);
```

.cpp файл

```
/**
* \brief Создание ресурса геометрии
* \param vertices Массив исходных вершин
* \param indices Массив индексов
*/
RglGeometryResource rglCreateGeometryResource(RglVertex* vertices, unsigned vertexCount, unsigned* indices, unsigned indexCount)
{
    auto resource = new GeometryResource(std::vector<RglVertex>(vertices, vertices + vertexCount), std::vector<GLuint>(indices, indices + indexCount));
    return reinterpret_cast<RglGeometryResource>(resource);
}

/**
* \brief Уничтожение ресурса геометрии
* \param resource Хендл ресурса
*/
void rglDestroyGeometryResource(RglGeometryResource* resource)
{
    GeometryResource* pGeometryResource = reinterpret_cast<GeometryResource*>(*resource);
    delete pGeometryResource;
    *resource = nullptr;
}
```

То есть в .h файле, который и будет подключаться к сторонним проектам у меня вовсе не иклюдятся необходимые классы, которые в библиотеке присутствуют, они инклюдятся только в .cpp файле, где я с ними и произвожу всяческие операции. По сути у меня получается что-то вроде C-шной обертки над ООП-шной С++ библиотекой.

Ах да, структура `RglVertex`, которая засветилась в примере, это структура состоящая исключительно из обычных стандартных полей (float) поэтому вероятность того что она будет одинакова в самой библиотеке и приложении которое ее использует крайне высока (поэтому я ее смело использую и в интерфейсе и внутри)

структура `RglVertex`:

```
struct RglVertex
{
    struct { float x; float y; float z; } position;
    struct { float r; float g; float b; } color;
    struct { float u; float v; } uv;
    struct { float x; float y; float z; } normal;
};
```

**Вроде бы все сходится и работает, но**

Я задумался - а что будет, если кто-то удалит ресурс который в данный момент используется (то есть вызовет rglDestroyGeometryResource раньше чем надо), как я смогу в самой библиотеке проверить что указатель более не валидный? nullptr, который я присваиваю после delete, он ведь присваивается копии, но не тому указателю, который есть "внутри самой библиотеки"...

**Вопрос:**

Как сделать так, чтобы в самой библиотеке можно было проверять валидность указателей? Каким будет наиболее правильный подход? Можно ли как-то здесь использовать умные указатели, могут ли они помочь в данной ситуации (например, функция создания ресурса будет возвращать хендл на умный указатель, а не на сам ресурс, или что-то вроде того), или здесь стоит применить какой-то совершенно иной подход?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А стоит ли вообще так заботиться о стреляющих по своим ногам? (прежде чем возражать, задумайтесь вообще о количестве способов случайно испортить память (внутренние структуры) в вашей dll)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Понятие "хэндл" обычно подразумевает, то это не просто голый указатель, а некоторый токен для обращения к какому-то ресурсу. Наивный вариант будет генерировать рандомный id `uintptr_t` и хранить объекты в `std::unordered_map<std::uintptr_t, GeometryResource>`, отдавая id в качестве `RglGeometryResource`.

Кроме того, при написании С врапперов недопустимо позволять исключениям проходить через границу языков.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что при создании очередного объекта он помещается в unordered_map (если это не копируемый ресурс, то при помощи move), затем, при вызове методов уничтожения он удаляется из map (тем самым вызывается его деструктор) и затем, другие объекты, которые используют этот ресурс, смогут просто проверить есть ли такой ключ в map'е? Получается это должен быть некий глобальный map, а у других классов не должно быть просто полей-указателей, это должны быть именно хендлы-ключи map'ов? То есть, если например у класса Mesh есть поле GeometryResource, то это должен быть именно ID?

Comment: @AlexNem При создании очередного объекта имеет смысл сразу размещать его в контейнере без копирования или перемещения. Мап должен быть глобальным, а обращение к ресурсам (во всяком случае из вке) - только по id. Кроме отслеживания валидности идентификаторов ресурсов такой глобальный мап может использоваться для отслеживания и форсирования ограничений на количество одновременно запрашиваемых ресурсов.